# Ищу готовую вёрстку (код), чтобы сгрупировать ссылки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет. Есть много ссылок, хочу сделать их классификацию (группировку). Выйдет некий каталог. Возможно кто-то знает, где можно взять готовую вёрстку (пусть самый просто html+css). Нужно что-то наподобие как на изображении снизу или похоже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пфффф... подержи моё пиво

Answer (score 1):

Данный пример скорее всего был реализован при помощи [`columns`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/columns)

```css
.link-group {
  display: block;
  columns: 4 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.link-group a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-group">
  <a href="#">Задача про бабушку и помидоры</a>
  <a href="#">Хитрый электрик</a>
  <a href="#">Как сделать свой таймер-напоминалку</a>
  <a href="#">Почему Sublime Text – это круто</a>
  <a href="#">Поговорим о Якубовиче</a>
  <a href="#">Как стать контент-менеджером</a>
  <a href="#">Задача про сторожа и фонарик</a>
  <a href="#">О названиях функций</a>
</div>
```